# VS Code local debugging of Azure Functions (v2.0) in Javascript: how to show ONLY my console.log() messages?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I tried to capture the issue context in the title, but in case it's unclear:

1. I'm developing/testing locally in VS Code.
2. I'm using Azure Functions v2.0.
3. I'm writing in JavaScript.

I can see both console.log() messages and context.log() messages in the Terminal window.  (The two calls behave EXACTLY the same in this case.)  The problem is that at runtime, the terminal window is also flooded with other messages emanating from the Azure Function runtime.  There are so many other messages that finding the console/context.log() messages is difficult.

I've resorted to using a delimiter (line of asterisks) to try to highlight what I want, but surely there's a better way to do this.

Here's an example:

[image]

I've read up on configuring log levels and categories in the host.json file, and have tried every permutation I can think of, but it either suppresses *only* my messages, or makes no difference at all.

How can I suppress ONLY the automatic messages, and leave only mine?  Or is there a way to direct console/context.log() output to another window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let your function app read a setting before starting.

Set `logging:logLevel:Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.SystemTraceMiddleware` to `None` in `local.settings.json` can disable the verbose console logs:

**`local.settings.json`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "logging:logLevel:Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.SystemTraceMiddleware": "None"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, Googling that setting, the answer above apparently comes from https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1440.  There are other possible settings to configure that might cut out some other log messages from showing up during local dev.